# Formatting a signature card in HTML with an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an image next to my signature line details.   However, when I use the code below, the last two lines of the text are aligned **under** the signature.  How can I modify the code?

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

p.Name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
<p class="Name">John Smith</p>
<p>123 Main Street</p>
<p>Anytown, USA</p>
<p>123 4567</p>
<p>johnsmith@gmail.com</p>
```

Comment: This is normal [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) behavior. Did you look into that? I suggest modern layout techniques instead.

Comment: @isherwood. I'm just trying to format a signature line without learning all modern layout techniques.  I'm an able but not expert programmer.

Comment: @isherwood also, how do I access a local image file?

Comment: Please don't ask new, unrelated questions in comments. Short answer: you don't. The browser doesn't have access to your file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Here we are using **display: flex;**

```css
.twoColumns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 28px;
}

p.Name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="twoColumns">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <p class="Name">John Smith</p>
    <p>123 Main Street</p>
    <p>Anytown, USA</p>
    <p>123 4567</p>
    <p>johnsmith@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but you should've implemented it with the original code. You've lost some of the styling. Also, there's a class in the CSS that isn't being used, and the image takes up too much space.

Comment: It worked, dogmatic quibbles aside.  Thank you and apologies for the delay in recognising your solution.